# SQL Linked server query very very slow

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am extracting large amount of data via linked server from VIEWS. I am using SQL Server 2012 and linked server is SQL Server 2008

My select statement is

```
SELECT * INTO MY_LOCAL_TABLE
FROM 
(    SELECT * FROM LINKEDSERVER.DB.TABLE.VIEW
     WHERE DATE>'2012-01-01' AND ID IN (SELECT ID FROM MY_LOCAL_VIEW) 
) Q
```

I am expecting 300K rows for nearly 700+ IDs. before it used to take couple of hours but now its take more than a 20 hr!!

Could you please suggest any alternative solution for this PAIN??

Very many thanks in advance!

Comment: Are the views indexed? if not do they contain sub queries? if not can you add an index to these views.

Comment: and do the views call other views, alawys a performance no-no espcially over a linked server.

Comment: yes the views are indexed properly. If I use OPENQUERY, does it makes any difference? or SSIS Package?

Comment: Another issue in this instance could be permissions with a linked server < 2012 SP1. Take a look at [this link](https://thomaslarock.com/2013/05/top-3-performance-killers-for-linked-server-queries/) and the number 1 listed issue - "Insufficent permissions"

Answer (score 59):

When you use a 4-part name such as `[server].db.dbo.table`, especially in a `join`, often times the entire table is copied over the wire to the local machine, which is obviously not ideal.

A better approach is to use an `OPENQUERY` -- which is handled at the source (linked server).

Try:

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENQUERY([LINKEDSERVER], 'SELECT * FROM DB.TABLE.VIEW WHERE DATE>'2012-01-01')
AND ID IN (SELECT ID FROM MY_LOCAL_VIEW)
```

With this approach the linked server will return all rows for date > x, and then the local server will filter that by ID's in your local table.

Of course, indexing will still play a factor for doing `SELECT * FROM DB.TABLE.VIEW WHERE DATE>'2012-01-01`.

Another approach, which I use on large subsets, is to dump the local ID's to the remote server, THEN handle it all remotely, such as:

```
    -- copy local table to linked server by executing remote query 
    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @SQL = 'SELECT ID INTO db.dbo.tmpTable FROM [SERVER].DB.DBO.MY_LOCAL_VIEW'
    EXEC(@SQL) AT [LINKEDSERVER]

   -- index remote table?!?
    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @SQL = 'CREATE INDEX [IXTMP] ON db.dbo.tmpTable (ID)'
    EXEC(@SQL) AT [LINKEDSERVER]

    -- run query on local machine against both remote tables
    SELECT *
    -- INTO sometable
    FROM OPENQUERY([LINKEDSERVER], 'SELECT * 
                                    FROM DB.TABLE.VIEW
                                    WHERE DATE>''2012-01-01''
                                    AND ID IN (SELECT ID FROM db.dbo.tmpTable)')

    -- now drop remote temp table of id's
    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @SQL = 'DROP TABLE db.dbo.tmpTable'
    EXEC(@SQL) AT [LINKEDSERVER]
```

If the local view is also large, then you may consider executing a remote query that uses an openquery back to the local machine (assuming the remote machine has the local as a link).

```
-- copy local table to linked server by executing remote query 
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @SQL = 'SELECT ID INTO db.dbo.tmpTable FROM OPENQUERY([SERVER], ''SELECT ID FROM DB.DBO.MY_LOCAL_VIEW'')'
EXEC(@SQL) AT [LINKEDSERVER]
```

Comment: +1 Indeed a good approach. Didn't knew about this (I mean openquery factor).

Comment: Humm... this seems good idea to me. I am not sure if I have access to create temp table on linked server or not but I will definitely try your suggestion as linked server contain more than 50K IDs!! thanks

Comment: It's possible put the ID's into a true temporary table (#table) -- everyone should have access to create them, and run it all in one go.  You can always create a user table in tempdb too, doesn't have to be in your work db.

Comment: If you can't make tabled in tempdb you could concatenate all the IDs together and use an `'SELECT * FROM DB.TABLE.VIEW WHERE DATE>'2012-01-01 and ID in (' + @concatednatedListOfIds + ')'` in the openquery. You said the list isn't *that* long. If your list is super long then this probably isn't a good idea.

Comment: Good idea... you cant use variables in the ooenquery so it would require building another dynamic sql string, but definitely another solid idea.

Comment: Hi Guys, I can't create temp table on remote server cz of account restriction. i have been given Public access to only one DB which consists of those views only!! my list of ID is bit long couldnt concate and pass to the remote query so i have requested bit more access so that i can at least create temp tables. by the way very many thanks for the help. Regards

Answer (score 2):

Others have already suggested about indexing. So I am not going there. suggest another option, if you could change that inner query

```
 SELECT * FROM LINKEDSERVER.DB.TABLE.VIEW
 WHERE DATE>'2012-01-01' AND ID IN (SELECT ID FROM MY_LOCAL_VIEW)
```

To a `joined` query using `inner join` since you said having 700+ inlist elements. give it a try.

```
   SELECT lnv.* FROM LINKEDSERVER.DB.TABLE.VIEW lnv
   inner join MY_LOCAL_VIEW mcv
   on lnv.ID = mcv.ID
   and lnv.DATE > '2012-01-01'
```

Comment: Cross server joins very often lead to entire tables copying to the local machine, this should only be done on very small tables you can afford to have this happen to.

Comment: @JiggsJedi, that's quite true (again, I have mentioned in my answer .. it's a suggestion worth trying once) but if the joined tables are not big enough this will give performance boost most of the time (per my observation).

Answer (score 0):

You can also try wrapping your query in an `EXEC` statement to avoid copying more data than necessary to your server:

```
EXEC('SELECT * FROM DB.TABLE.VIEW
     WHERE DATE>'+''''+'2012-01-01'+''''+' AND ID IN (SELECT ID FROM MY_LOCAL_VIEW)') AT LINKEDSERVER
```