# SQL Server linked server performance on Oracle after upgrade 2008->2016

Tags: sql-server, performance, oracle11g, linked-server

I have had a running SQL Server 2008 instance for years where I have several interfaces to an ora11 database exchanging data day for day, everything has been running correctly.

For few days now since upgrading from SQL Server 2008R2 to 2016 and importing the whole SQL Server 2008 database into our new SQL Server 2016 instance.

We were re-establishing our interfaces and everything looked good. I had created the linked server with an ora11 client connecting to the ora11-db. connected worked fine.

But since then, the stored-procedures which I was using in my interfaces, took a lot of more time for running. On SQL Server 2008R2, the linked server updates to ora11 took about a few minutes. The completely same procedure now takes about a few hours for the same number of rows updating to oracle.

My interface procedures almost look like this:

- collect local data using a cursor
- iterate through the cursor, looking in the remote database using linked server if the record exists
- insert the missing record using linked server in Oracle db
- close everything and complete

Why is it suddenly that much slower using the exactly the same source? Is there anything new in SQL Server 2016 which needs to be configured properly?

What is wrong?

Comment: Do you have all the indexes in place? if it is the first time you are ruining the stored procedure excution sql plans may not exists yet. Running same stored procedure manually few time will create these plans

Comment: Did you rebuild all indexes? Have you the ability to compare plans from 2008R2 and 2016 instances? Perhaps try using OPENQUERY()? : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24272652/sql-linked-server-query-very-very-slow

Comment: Indexes? You are talking about the indexes on the sql16? actually i'm online running one select against local sql16 and then using cursor to insert  rows in ora11. i as well tried openquery, but didnt gain any speed

Comment: I didnt find any solution so far.
what i did:
- change the insert into the linked ora-server-db using openquery
- see for missing indexes and recreated plans
- ran a trace on the oracle side, but without any troubles

actually what previously took about several minutes now takes about few hours.
another thing which might be not that optimal is, that within my cursor i have to select the nextval from a sequence and after that i can insert.
i didnt find any option to send a insert including an nextval from a sequence within the same insert-statement

any help appriciated